# URL Schemes and Facebook App 5.0

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

There's a question already related to groups, but it seems it's much more than that. Have URL schemes been completely thrown out of the new app (aside from the generic fb://), or is there a new list of supported schemes?

In particular, we can't get to a place details page. I've also tried /pages, /page, /places, /place...

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about those urls... but I just posted what I believe is a solution for facebook business pages.. it may help?  Here it is below:

OK .. seriously this took me about 90 minutes of research to figure out. It works currently under facebook ios 5.0.1 for iPhone.. haven't tried it in iPad yet.

The url is fb://profile/132753734806

NOW the important part is that number. That links to one of my clients, Charles Scott. HOWEVER, that's not their FBID or Page ID.. their Page ID is 10150348920319807

so you would think it should be fb://profile/10150348920319807 but that gives me an error.

Here's how you get the correct code.. click on any of your page's photos.. here's an example for my client https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150348920319807&set=a.10150348920314807.356942.132753734806&type=1&theater

if you notice the FBID that does not work follows fbid= in that URL.. the number you WANT is just before the &type=1theater but following that last period. 132753734806 is the correct code to punch in after fb://profile/

I hope that makes some sense... I know zero about code or coding but this was bothering me so much and I knew there was a way.

Now, the two questions I would love to have answered/working.. 1. if this could work on android phones 2. create a working qr code for this url so people can scan with ios devices and have it open automatically

Good luck and I hope this helps everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I tried Alessandro's way but did not succeed - the number he mentioned is new every time.

I tried fb://profile?id={pageId} and it worked in my case. {pageId} is simple page id number without any tricks. Facebook app version is 5.0.1